# composeTestRule not work in Scenario() in kaspresso

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, junit4, android-testing

I'm trying to write Scenario() with composeTestRule in Kaspresso, but I get an error:

```
Test not setup properly. Use a ComposeTestRule in your test to be able to interact with composables
```

My scenario for example:

```
class FillOtp(
) : Scenario() {

    override val steps: TestContext<Unit>.() -> Unit = {

        val baseTest = BaseTest()

        step("Write 0000") {
                baseTest.composeTestRule
                    .onNodeWithTag("test")
                    .performClick()
                MyScreen {
                    pinEdit {
                        typeText("0000")
                    }
                    continueBtn.click()
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But I have added composeTestRule in BaseTest() class. And composeTestRule works successfully in tests without Scenario()

could you help me solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On another site I was offered the answer:

You can pass it to the constructor from the test:

```
class MyScenario(semanticsProvider: SemanticsNodeInteractionsProvider) : Scenario() {
 override val steps: TestContext<Unit>.() -> Unit = {
  semanticsProvider.onNode(...)
 }
}
```

And in test:

```
scenario(MyScenario(composeTestRule))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example for Kaspresso users:
In test:

```
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<HomeActivity>()
private fun clickAddAndSearch(types: String, something: String) {
    run {
        addAlertFabBtn.click()
        scenario(
            GetSomethingScenario(1, types, something, composeTestRule)
        )
    }
}
```

In scenario:

```
class GetSomethingScenario<ScenarioData>(
    index: Int,
    type: String,
    something: String,
    semanticsProvider: SemanticsNodeInteractionsProvider,
) : BaseScenario<ScenarioData>() {
     semanticsProvider.onNodeWithText(type).performClick()
}
```